# OpenVPN drops connection and then reconnects constantly

Tags: linux, openvpn

I have a Linux client I am connecting to an OpenVPN host.
The client connects fine, and with verb=5 I see multiple reads and writes on the client:

```
LOG:1391694246,I,Initialization Sequence Completed 
LOG:1391694246,D,TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]2xx.180.7.10:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 30 ] 
LOG:1391694246,D,TUN READ [76] 
LOG:1391694246,D,TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [117] to [AF_INET]2xx.180.7.10:443: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=116 
LOG:1391694246,D,TUN READ [76] 
LOG:1391694246,D,TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [117] to [AF_INET]2xx.180.7.10:443: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=116 
LOG:1391694247,D,TUN READ [76] 
LOG:1391694247,D,TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [117] to [AF_INET]2xx.180.7.10:443: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=116 
LOG:1391694249,D,TUN READ [76] 
LOG:1391694249,D,TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [117] to [AF_INET]2xx.180.7.10:443: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=116 
LOG:1391694253,D,TUN READ [76] 
LOG:1391694253,D,TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [117] to [AF_INET]2xx.180.7.10:443: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=116
```

Then, after a few seconds (anywhere between 15 and 30 seconds) this happens:

```
LOG:1391694303,D,TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [101] to [AF_INET]2xx.180.7.10:443: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=100
LOG:1391694305,D,TUN READ [60]
LOG:1391694305,D,TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [101] to [AF_INET]2xx.180.7.10:443: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=100
LOG:1391694306,I,[vpn] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
LOG:1391694306,,TCP/UDP: Closing socket
LOG:1391694306,,/sbin/ip route del xx.96.4.137/32
LOG:1391694306,,/sbin/ip route del 2xx.180.0.0/18
LOG:1391694306,,/sbin/ip route del 2xx.157.192.0/18
LOG:1391694306,,/sbin/ip route del xx.123.92.0/26
LOG:1391694306,,/sbin/ip route del xx.123.79.192/26
LOG:1391694306,,/sbin/ip route del xx.123.77.0/25
LOG:1391694306,,/sbin/ip route del xx.250.30.128/27
LOG:1391694306,,/sbin/ip route del xx.250.30.160/27
LOG:1391694306,,/sbin/ip route del 1xx.112.245.0/24
LOG:1391694306,,/sbin/ip route del 1xx.207.0.0/16
LOG:1391694306,,Closing TUN/TAP interface
LOG:1391694306,I,/sbin/ip addr del dev tun0 local 1xx.19.23.64 peer 1xx.19.0.0
LOG:1391694306,I,SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
LOG:1391694306,,Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

This is odd because they seem to be communicating right up until the "inactivity timeout". Also, the server pushes `ping=10,ping-restart=60`- so I would think this is happening too fast. Not sure what's happening.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a directive like this in your `server.conf` : `keepalive 10 120` ?

Comment: @user2196728: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the server.conf, so I can't say for sure. I would think the line would be like `keepalive 10 60` since I get a `Received control message: PUSH_REPLY,ping 10,ping-restart 60` message when I connect to the VPN.